# How can I serve a tracking image that won't get removed by Hotmail?

Tags: asp.net, .net, email

I'm building an emailshot tracking function in my ASP.NET site which will serve up a linked image when the email is opened, so allowing me to count the email opens.

It's all above-board, opted-in etc, etc, and I've tried two methods:

- calling a `.aspx` page that serves (direct to the Response stream) a Base64-encoded image stored in a database
- calling a `.ashx` HTTP handler that serves an image from a physical folder

Both of these techniques work absolutely fine - the image is served, and I can process the hit in the page code - if I use my POP email or my Gmail accounts.

However, Hotmail blocks them both.  It doesn't even give the option of displaying images - there's no trace of the original link if I `View Source` on the browser email display.

Links to images only seem to display correctly in the Hotmail browser window if I:

- Use an actual domain name in the link (rather than an IP address or localhost for testing) AND
- Link to physical files (rather than pages that serve them) using `<img src="http://domain/imagefilename.ext"/>`.

Is there an alternate approach that will at least give the option of viewing the image?  I'm not trying to conceal the tracking in any way - there will usually be other linked images in the emails anyway.

Nor does the thing being served have to be an image - is there anything else that can be served (and hence counted) that isn't treated as suspicious by over-zealous mail servers such as Hotmail?

Cheers.

Comment: Just throwing this out there. Maybe add a querystring value at the end of the url? And configure IIS to handle that extension?

Comment: You could create a special image handler mapping that serves images as .jpg (or whatever) - maybe from a special folder so as to not interfere with normal image serving. I don't know exactly what the rules are but I'd expect services to strip images that aren't images to avoid exactly what you're trying to do - which is track the user.

Comment: I like Rick's idea. You may be able to dynamically generate an image for a path like: http://domain/emailBlasts/emailBlastID/UserIdGUID.jpg

Comment: If you find an answer to this question, make sure to file a bug report with the details so they can fix the problem.

Comment: Ok, I've got it working - using Shai's suggestion (although since I'm using IIS7 and ASP.NET, I can do it by adding a handler line to web.config, rather than change IIS itself).  No saying it will always work, but it seems to for now.  For Hotmail, it's still blocked if the sender isn't either an existing contact, or in the recipient's safe senders list, but this is fine, since the sender is a legitimate sender of opted-in newsletters.  Many thanks!  @Shai - if you'd like to add an answer, I'll accept it.  Thanks too for the other suggestions - might need those too at some point.

Comment: Thanks for following up on this question. Too many people find the solution and never update their original question. I would upvote your question again if I could :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a querystring value at the end of the url. And then configure IIS to handle that extension.

Answer (score 0):

WELL what are you asking is a nightmare for email server.this same technique is used by spammers to get valid emailid out of junk emailids. For now i can assure you tracking opening of email is impossible using any white hat or gray hat techniques on any reputiable servers.

plese see these links for more details:-
http://emailuniverse.com/ezine-tips/?id=502
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22662/way-to-ensure-that-my-sent-email-was-read

However dont take myword 'impossible' for granted, there are some protected techineques available but i am not sure about it
http://mailchimp.com/
good luck